# import error:DLL failed to load: could not find systematic procedure

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

While running python selenium webdriver using python.it is showing the above error.for clear understanding I am attaching [fidn the image for error inoccured while running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDWvT.png)the image pls find it.

Comment: You should post your stack trace here, not as an image!

Comment: do you have firefox geckodriver in the folder from where you are calling the script

Comment: yes i have and im giving the path also but still it is showing error